# linq and datagridview

Tags: linq, datagridview

why does the following show only the length of the fields inside the grid and not the data?
(column header in grid is also length)

```
dim q as IQueryable = (from p in DB.Table select p.field1)
```

while this shows both columns and tha data

```
dim q as IQueryable = (from p in DB.Table select p.field1, p.field2)
```

both fields are strings

thanks in advance

Comment: ahh forgot to say

this works: 
dim q as IQueryable = (from p in DB.Table select new with{p.field1})

i just want to understand why? :)

Comment: You can edit your question to add more information. It would be clearer than posting a comment.